# Using pandas resample / rolling_sum to calculate seconds time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
(Pdb) self.df.columns
Index([u'distinct_id', u'event_name', u'item_id', u'player_time', u'time',
       u'video_id'],
      dtype='object')
```

`player_time` is a float value, and it is not unique. My end goal is to count the number of events (`event_name`) that happen at any given second (`player_time`) and then if needed, perform a rolling-sum across different intervals:

To get the number of events that happen at any given second, I can use groupby:

```
(Pdb) grouped_df = self.df.groupby(self.df.player_time).count(); grouped_df
             distinct_id  event_name  item_id  time  video_id
player_time
16                     1           1        1     1         1
25                     0           2        1     1         1
28                     1           1        1     1         1
29                     1           1        1     1         1
36                     1           1        1     1         1
46                     1           1        1     1         1
70                     1           1        1     1         1
77                     1           1        1     1         1
95                     1           1        1     1         1
107                    1           1        1     1         1
117                    1           1        1     1         1
118                    1           1        1     1         1
131                    0           2        1     1         1
153                    1           1        1     1         1
155                    1           1        1     1         1
163                    1           1        1     1         1
177                    1           1        1     1         1
182                    1           1        1     1         1
183                    1           1        1     1         1
196                    1           1        1     1         1
```

As you can see there was one event per second for every second except 25 and 131. Now I want to do is something similiar to

```
(Pdb) grouped_df.resample('10s',how='sum')
*** TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex
```

But I am not set up to do that right now. What is the best way to accomplish this goal? I looked at `pandas.rolling_sum` and it looks like it might be able to do the job also, I just cant get it do what I am describing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a series sum function and apply it to a `groupby()`:

```
# RESET TO DATA FRAME
grouped_df = self.df.groupby(self.df.player_time).count().reset_index()

# SERIES SUM FUNCTION (SUMS EVERY LAST 10 VALUES OF PLAYER_TIME)
def intsum(x):
    if x < 10:        
        ser = groupdf.event_name[(groupdf.player_time < x)]
    else:
        ser = groupdf.event_name[(groupdf.player_time >= x - 10) & (groupdf.player_time < x)]
    return ser.sum()    

# APPLY FUNCTION
groupdf['intervalSum'] = groupdf['player_time'].apply(intsum)

print(groupdf)
```

**Output**

```
    player_time  distinct_id  event_name  item_id  time  video_id  intervalSum
0            16            1           1        1     1         1            0
1            25            0           2        1     1         1            1
2            28            1           1        1     1         1            2
3            29            1           1        1     1         1            3
4            36            1           1        1     1         1            2
5            46            1           1        1     1         1            1
6            70            1           1        1     1         1            0
7            77            1           1        1     1         1            1
8            95            1           1        1     1         1            0
9           107            1           1        1     1         1            0
10          117            1           1        1     1         1            1
11          118            1           1        1     1         1            1
12          131            0           2        1     1         1            0
13          153            1           1        1     1         1            0
14          155            1           1        1     1         1            1
15          163            1           1        1     1         1            2
16          177            1           1        1     1         1            0
17          182            1           1        1     1         1            1
18          183            1           1        1     1         1            2
19          196            1           1        1     1         1            0
```

Comment: awesome - thanks you - what is the purpose of the reset_index call ?

Comment: Great! The `reset_index()` is to convert pandas groupby object back to data frame (fills all rows). Groupbys maintain hierarchical indexing. Remove if not needed.